# Technique or tool to get CSS element list for deeply nested elements quickly

Tags: html, css, google-chrome-devtools

I am using Chrome dev tools and am working on a code base I did not create.

There are deeply nested elements that I need to reach all over the place. In order to select them with CSS I feel like I'm manually following the list of HTML elements *with my eyes* ( which is taking me forever).

There should just be a tool that allows me to select the top element and the (deeply) nested element I want  -  then give me the hierarchy in a CSS formatted block so I can go to work.

I am curious if such a tool exists or if there is an equivalent (possibly in Chrome dev tools somewhere? ).

Thank you.

Comment: This is a pretty legitimate question... *researching*

Comment: I don't think I understand what you want. I thought I did but after reading it again I realize I was off... Could you maybe give a simple code example and maybe what the "tool" would accomplish or output?

Comment: I think the OP means, given N nested elements, copy all the CSS rules applying to all of them in one go.

Answer (score 3):

I'm a little unclear on the question (so I probably shouldn't be answering it!) but if you are asking for a way to quickly get a CSS selector for deeply nested elements you might try Firebug.

1. Inspect the element
2. Right click in the style panel to the right on the HTML panel
3. Select 'Add Rule'.

Does a very good job of sorting out the required specificity.

As @TaoistWA pointed out in the comments, "Copy CSS Path" is another option.

1. Inspect the element
2. Right click on the element in the HTML panel
3. Select 'Copy CSS Path'.

You can, of course, combine them both within the style panel to test your changes on the fly.

Comment: I think you are off. I was unclear too but just by reading the first line of the question you can see that the OP is using Chromes dev tools. This is the equivalent to firebug for Chrome so he is already knows how to use a dev console.

Comment: @DutGRIFF you might be right. But Firebug has a feature Chrome's dev tools doesn't. Well, it does actually have it (little plus sign in the CSS panel) but it doesn't do as much DOM inspection. As an example, try inspecting the table that your comment is held in (just inside of `div.comments`) and select the 'add rule' function from both. Firebug gives you `#comments-21422129 > table {}` and Chrome gives you `table{}`

Comment: I see. Alright. This may actually be helpful. I think I was way wrong about what he wanted. You last comment just kinda helped me see what he may be trying to accomplish. Ha.

Comment: @Will I just downloaded firefox/firebug and tried to follow your instructions but the css tab doesn't give me an 'add rule' option. I'm on windows at the moment. I tried firebug light for chrome as well.

Comment: @Will there is a 'copy css path' option that I found in firefox. I'm wondering if that is what you're loosely referring to? Now I'm curious if there is a chrome equivalent.

Comment: @TaoistWA "Copy CSS path" might even be better than what I was talking about - forgot that existed! I will edit my answer (with better 'add rule' instructions as well).

Comment: I'll vote this up but it seriously seems like its too complicated compared to what should exist. Maybe I'm just not skilled enough yet as a dev but I really think this should be a common feature and a simple right click-hold operation. Especially with chrome

Comment: Really? It's two steps. Ctrl+Shift+C to inspect an element, right click on the styles panel and select 'Add Rule'. Or you can do 1000 steps and save us all the extra step by creating a plugin. ;) http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted.html https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Building_an_Extension